# Unable to use "Manage Content and Structure" after removing Project server form the SharePoint farm

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-project

We're no longer using Office Project Server, and I've removed it from the farm in which it was installed. However, now that it's been removed, I am unable to access the "Manage Content and Structure" link on some of our SharePoint sites. I get an error indicating that SharePoint

> Failed to find the XML file at location '12\Template\Features\PWSCommitments\feature.xml'

Anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: This is not a real answer but I once seen something similar. Project Server was removed and than various problems occurred with SharePoint.  Have you tried repairing SharePoint installation?

Answer (score 0):

Manage Content and Structure is part of the MOSS functionality.  I have to assume that when you uninstalled Project server it deactived the Publishing Feature (sorry I do not have the exact name(s)).

I suggest that you create a new Publishing Collaboration site and see which features are activated.  If you do not see Publishing Collaboration sites as one of the options then you will need to repair your SharePoint installation.